# Kafka to Tableau connectivity

Tags: tableau-api

Can you guys help on connecting Tableau to Kafka?
I'm trying to display Real time Graph analysis with the Help of Tableau.

Alternatively Is it possible for Tableau to connect to a specific port where data is being sent by Kafka?

Thanks,
Abhi

Comment: I do not believe Tableau connects to any port for a real-time updates scenario. You can schedule it to read from a data repository on a schedule..   It pulls the data during this read operation. I do not believe pushing data to the dashboard is a supported scenario

Answer (score 3):

Kafka will not be sending data to any port. You will need to write a consumer which can push data to anywhere you need. In your case, you will need a consumer writing to where Tableau can read from.

Answer (score 0):

By now Tableau does not have a connector for Kafka.

If you want to graph Kafka data in Tableau you have two options:

1 - Use Kafka Connect to dump the data to a database that Tableau supports.

2 - Use a Tableau/Python Server (https://github.com/tableau/TabPy)

In the second case you need some code that consumes the data from Kafka.
*BE CAREFUL* to limit the amount of messages you consume and the time you spend waiting for that values.